# User privileges docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I want to set user privileges and use node user

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    user: "node:node"
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - /var/redis/data:/data
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY package*.json ./

RUN mkdir app && chown -R node:node .

RUN npm i -g nodemon

USER node

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node . .

CMD ["nodemon", "-L", "--inspect=0.0.0.0",  "index.js"]
```

and that's my output inside the container:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSeIT.jpg).
So, it sets node user in my first folder, but it doesn't set node user in /usr/src/app. It seems to be a problem with volume,but there is no result even if I set user in my docker-compose file(initially there was no user field)

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding everything the `Dockerfile` does in the `/usr/src/app` directory, including setting filesystem permissions.

Comment: @DavidMaze is it possible to solve this problems without removing volumes? I need volumes to use debugger and nodemon

Comment: Remove `COPY --chown=node:node . .` from the Dockerfile. You do the same by mounting the volume. Also remove the volume mount for `node_modules` since that is already part of the other mount declaration. On a more general note, you shouldn't use Docker for development: it is a great tool to deliver your product but it will slow down your development process.

Comment: _"but it doesn't set node user in /usr/src/app"_. It shouldn't. Files in `/usr/src/app` have host system permissions. It seems that the owner of `/usr/src/app` doesn't have UID=1000. You may create a group with gid equal to the owner of `/usr/src/app` and add "node" user to that group in Dockerfile or set gid=1000 for files in `/usr/src/app` to give "node" user access to them.

Comment: See also [Docker file permissions](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/8fxpyn/docker_file_permissions/)